# Excel VBA - Run a macro based on a range of dropdown lists

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu

It's been a few years since VBA class so please respond as if you were writing in an "Excel VBA for Dummies" book.

In column G, each cell in range G2:G1001 is an individual data validation drop down list of all the worksheets in my workbook. I have a macro that when you select "Questar" from the dropdown in cell "G2", it copies cells A2:F2 and pastes them to the worksheet titled "Questar" in the first empty row. That all works fine.

However, my issue is it only works in cell G2. I have data in rows 2-1001 and I need this to work for all cells G2:G1001. Here is what I have so far and works for cell "G2":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G2:G1001")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("G2")
            Case "Questar": Questar
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

I think that the Select Case Range("G2") needs to change but I have tried everything.

Here is my Questar macro code:

```
Sub Questar()

    Worksheets("AFCU Auto-Add").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6), ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)).Copy
    Worksheets("Questar").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Sheets("AFCU Auto-Add").Select
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6), ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows(1).Delete
    Range("G2").Select

End Sub
```

I will eventually add more cases but I want to get one worksheet working correctly before adding more cases and macros. Any suggestions?

Comment: The simplest change would be to replace `Select Case Range("G2")` with `Select Case Target.Value` - that will cause it to look at the Target cell (or, unfortunately - because it complicates things, all cells) which generated the `Change` event.  But if you need to let the `Questar` macro know which cells to copy, etc, you may need to pass something like `Target.Row` as a parameter to Questar so that it can then operate on the appropriate data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: updated to single procedure, assuming all sheets exist which are named in column G...

Something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, rngDel As Range

    On Error GoTo haveError

    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("G2:G1001"))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
                'copy to appropiate sheet
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(c.Value).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
                    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, rng.Cells.Count).Value = _
                                     c.EntireRow.Range("A1:F1").Value
                End With

                'build up a range of rows to delete...
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDel = c
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(c, rngDel)
                End If

            End If
        Next c

        'any rows to delete?
        If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If

    End If

    Exit Sub

haveError:
    'make sure to re-enable events in the case of an error
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry still very new. Can you give me an example of how to add argument to my Questar sub?

Comment: Sorry again. I see how you passed the argument but I don't understand what to do with the rest of my Questar macro.  Also, I don't always want A1:F1, it will just be the columns to the left of whatever G cell I selected. I have edited my original question to include my entire Questar code. Anyway you can put your suggestion into the macro and reply with the entire macro updated? It would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You are right that the related subs will just replace `Questar`. I have other worksheet names from the list: RMPower, Water, Groceries, etc. Can you show me an example of how to pass a second String parameter?

Comment: Tim, I had a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40538259/7129429. Do you mind taking a look?