# Delete Data from a Worksheet If Selection from Dropdown List is Changed

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

Follow up question to a previously answered question: [Excel VBA - Run a macro based on a range of dropdown lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478350/excel-vba-run-a-macro-based-on-a-range-of-dropdown-lists).

Current: This is for a personal expense spreadsheet and I am using Column G on my `Master` worksheet to classify line item expenses imported from a .csv provided by my credit union. Each cell in Column G has a dropdown list which is the name of the other worksheets in my workbook: `Power`, `Gas`, `Groceries`, etc. Currently, when you make a selection from the Column G dropdown list, it copies `A1:F1` of the current row and pastes it to the next empty row of whatever worksheet was selected, e.g. `Power` or `Gas` or `Groceries`. All of that is finally working fine.

Problem: However, if I re-classify a line expense, e.g. from my original selection `Gas` and I change it to `Power` it will again copy `A1:F1` of the current row and move to the `Power` worksheet. That is great BUT I need it to remove the line we copied from our `Gas` tab.

Possible Solution?: The only way I can think of this is adding something like this... IF the dropdown is not blank and I change the original selection THEN I need to find an exact text copy of `A1:F1` (A1: Date, B1: No., C1: Description, D1: Debit, E1: Credit, F1: Notes - these will ("should") never be duplicate) from the original selection worksheet (`Gas`) and delete those cells and move up the below rows. I'm asking for help for someone to please write that above scenario in code and show me what it will look like in my current code (I understand VBA at a novice level - at best).

Here is my current code that runs once a dropdown value is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range, c As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("G2:G1001"))
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        Select Case c.Value
            Case "Power": Power c
            Case "Gas": Gas c
            Case "Water": Water c
            Case "Groceries, etc.": GroceriesEtc c
            Case "Eating Out": EatingOut c
            Case "Amazon": Amazon c
            Case "Home": Home c
            Case "Entertainment": Entertainment c
            Case "Auto": Auto c
            Case "Medical": Medical c
            Case "Dental": Dental c
            Case "Income": Income c
            Case "Other": Other c
        End Select
    Next c
End If
End Sub
```

Here is the case macro that is fired off from the above code (there is a similar macro for each case):

```
Sub Gas(c As Range)

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = c.EntireRow.Range("A1:F1") '<< A1:F1 here is *relative to c.EntireRow*

'copy the values
With Worksheets("Gas").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, rng.Cells.Count).Value = rng.Value
End With

End Sub
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: There needs to be some kind of unique identifier to look up old values.  Without knowing anything about the data, there is no way to help you. Can you provide sample workbook download link or screenshots of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You probably need to tweak it a bit, but it should get you going. I have added a global variable that you can store the previous value from the dropdown list.
In the `SelectionChange` I have tried to create an error handling to take care of multiple cells selected. If just 1 cell selected then that value will be bound to the global variable. Then you can use that variable to find the sheet of the previous value in the dropdown list, loop through the sheet, and delete the value.

First I have added this to your Gas, Power, etc. subs. to make them dynamic.

```
Sub Power(c As Range)

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = Range("A" & c.Row & ":F" & c.Row) '<< A1:F1 here is *relative to c.EntireRow*

    'copy the values
    With Worksheets("Power").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, rng.Cells.Count).Value = rng.Value

        ' Copy formating from Master Sheet
        With Worksheets("Master")
            Range("A" & c.Row & ":F" & c.Row).Copy
        End With
        .Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With

End Sub
```

Under the Master sheet (not module), I have added this:

```
' Add this to the absolute top of the sheet, must be outside a procedure (sub)
Option Explicit
Public cbxOldVal As String
Dim PrevVal As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

cbxOldVal = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If Selection.Rows.Count = 1 And Selection.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        PrevVal = Selection.Value
    Else
        PrevVal = Selection
    End If
End Sub
```

Add this to your `Worksheet_Change` event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range, c As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("G2:G1001"))

If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("G")) Is Nothing Then
    If PrevVal <> "" Or cbxOldVal <> "" Then
        If cbxOldVal = Target.Value Then
            MsgBox "You have to click on another cell " & vbNewLine & "and then click back on " & Target.Address & " to change the value", vbExclamation, "Error"
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column) = PrevVal
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Target.Value = "" Or Target.Value = PrevVal Then Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End If

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
' Your loop
```

Then I have added some code to your `Worksheet_Change` event. Add this to after the `End Select`.

```
    If cbxOldVal = "" Then
    ' do nothing

    Else

        With Worksheets(cbxOldVal)

            Dim i As Integer
            Dim strFindA As String, strFindB As String, strFindC As String
            Dim strFindD As String, strFindE As String, strFindF As String
            strFindA = Sheets("Master").Range("A" & c.Row)
            strFindB = Sheets("Master").Range("B" & c.Row)
            strFindC = Sheets("Master").Range("C" & c.Row)
            strFindD = Sheets("Master").Range("D" & c.Row)
            strFindE = Sheets("Master").Range("E" & c.Row)
            strFindF = Sheets("Master").Range("F" & c.Row)

            For i = 1 To 100    ' replace with lastrow

            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = strFindA _
            And .Cells(i, 2).Value = strFindB _
            And .Cells(i, 3).Value = strFindC _
            And .Cells(i, 4).Value = strFindD _
            And .Cells(i, 5).Value = strFindE _
            And .Cells(i, 6).Value = strFindF _
            Then

            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            MsgBox "deleted row " & i
            GoTo skip:

            End If

            Next i


        End With
    End If
skip:
```

Comment: Yes, I previously had that in there but I want my `Master` tab to have a list of all itemized expenses.

Comment: Now I am confused. You want it to be in the change procedure or you want to delete it somewhere else? Cant you just put it after the end of the case?

Comment: I don't want to cut and paste. I just want to copy and paste. The worksheet that has Column G should have the itemized line item expenses remain on the `Master` worksheet.

Comment: Ahh now I think I understood. I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @Bobby try it out now :-)

Comment: I added your code in and it is error free. However, it doesn't delete the code from the previous worksheet (original selection worksheet). Do you know if there is a way to message you and send you my workbook as a file so you can take a quick look at it?

Comment: I think you can just use any file sharing site. For instance this https://uploadfiles.io/

Comment: It seems like the problem was the formatting of the copied cells. I have added a code to the gas procedure that you need to copy to the rest. Should work now. Please test :-)

Comment: Just tested. Still is not deleting from the original selection worksheet though. Were you able to get it work? Also, was the only thing you changed the gas procedure?

Comment: It is, but you cannot stay in the same cell after selecting for instance gas. If you want to change the value from gas to power, then you need to click in another cell and click back to the cell and change it. I am working on an error message for this. But it should work fine as long as you do not stay in the same cell and keep changing the dropdown.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much for all your time and help and for before very specific in where to put the code and for the examples! You have been a lifesaver, I never would have got this!

Comment: If you have a new issue, you should create a new question :-)

Comment: I have added and edited my question. Can you please take a look since you are familiar with my problem and spreadsheet? It would be much appreciated! Thanks A TON in advance! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665650/excel-vba-copy-data-a-worksheet-if-selection-from-dropdown-list-is-changed