# Copy Data a Worksheet If Selection from Dropdown List is Changed

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

Follow up question to a previously answered question: [Excel VBA - Delete Data from a Worksheet If Selection from Dropdown List is Changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538259/excel-vba-delete-data-from-a-worksheet-if-selection-from-dropdown-list-is-chan)

Current: This is for a personal expense spreadsheet and I am using Column G on my Master worksheet to classify line item expenses imported from a .csv provided by my credit union. Each cell in Column G has a dropdown list which is the name of the other worksheets in my workbook: Power, Gas, Groceries, etc. Currently, when you make a selection from the Column G dropdown list, it copies A1:F1 of the current row and pastes it to the next empty row of whatever worksheet was selected, e.g. Power or Gas or Groceries.

Problem:

While I was testing the answer from my previous question, it worked fine. However, there are now some new issues not that I have thousand of rows of real data

**Issue #1:** The copy and pasting of rows to other worksheets only works for the first few times I select a worksheet from the dropdown. For example, in cell G2, I select "Eating Out" from the dropdown, it will copy A1:F1 to the eating out worksheet. However, if if I go to G11 and select Amazon it won't do anything. It seems to work on the first 3 or 4 rows that I try to do but doesn't work on the rest. When I say it won't work, it just doesn't copy to any worksheet.

**Issue #2:** I ran into a never-ending message box error. When the error message pops-up and says,

"You have to click on another cell " & vbNewLine & "and then click back on " & Target.Address & " to change the value""

I click OK, and it just pops up again and won't let me do anything else. It just keeps popping up and the only way to get rid of the error message is to Force Quit Excel.

**Issue #3:** I sporadically ran into an copy/paste issue. What happens (only sometimes) is that it would copy column A,B,C,D,E,F and then paste column A from the master worksheet to column A in the selection worksheet, BUT column C from the master worksheet to column B in the selection worksheet, column D from the master worksheet to column C in the selection worksheet, column E from the master worksheet to column D in the selection worksheet and column F from the master worksheet to column E in the selection worksheet. I have no idea what happened to Column B from the master worksheet (my guess is since Column B from the master worksheet is always blank, it decided not to copy it over to the new worksheet?)?

Here is my current code that runs once a dropdown value is changed:

```
Option Explicit
Public cbxOldVal As String
Dim PrevVal As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

cbxOldVal = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If Selection.Rows.Count = 1 And Selection.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        PrevVal = Selection.Value
    Else
        PrevVal = Selection
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range, c As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("G2:G30000"))

If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("G")) Is Nothing Then
    If PrevVal <> "" Or cbxOldVal <> "" Then
        If cbxOldVal = Target.Value Then
            MsgBox "You have to click on another cell " & vbNewLine & "and then click back on " & Target.Address & " to change the value", vbExclamation, "Error"
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column) = PrevVal
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Target.Value = "" Or Target.Value = PrevVal Then Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End If

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        Select Case c.Value
            Case "Power": Power c
            Case "Gas": Gas c
            Case "Water": Water c
            Case "Groceries, etc.": GroceriesEtc c
            Case "Eating Out": EatingOut c
            Case "Amazon": Amazon c
            Case "Home": Home c
            Case "Entertainment": Entertainment c
            Case "Auto": Auto c
            Case "Medical": Medical c
            Case "Dental": Dental c
            Case "Income": Income c
            Case "Labor": Labor c
            Case "Union Dues": UnionDues c
            Case "Other": Other c
        End Select

If cbxOldVal = "" Then
' do nothing

Else

    With Worksheets(cbxOldVal)

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim strFindA As String, strFindB As String, strFindC As String
        Dim strFindD As String, strFindE As String, strFindF As String
        strFindA = Sheets("Master").Range("A" & c.Row)
        strFindB = Sheets("Master").Range("B" & c.Row)
        strFindC = Sheets("Master").Range("C" & c.Row)
        strFindD = Sheets("Master").Range("D" & c.Row)
        strFindE = Sheets("Master").Range("E" & c.Row)
        strFindF = Sheets("Master").Range("F" & c.Row)

        For i = 1 To 100    ' replace with lastrow

        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = strFindA _
        And .Cells(i, 2).Value = strFindB _
        And .Cells(i, 3).Value = strFindC _
        And .Cells(i, 4).Value = strFindD _
        And .Cells(i, 5).Value = strFindE _
        And .Cells(i, 6).Value = strFindF _
        Then

        .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        MsgBox "Deleted Row " & i
        GoTo skip:

        End If

        Next i

    End With
End If
skip:

    Next c
End If
End Sub
```

Here is the case macro that is fired off from the above code (there is a similar macro for each case). These are in the Module:

```
Sub Power(c As Range)

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Nothing
Set rng = Range("A" & c.Row & ":F" & c.Row) '<< A1:F1 here is *relative to c.EntireRow*

'copy the values
With Worksheets("Power").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, rng.Cells.Count).Value = rng.Value

    ' Copy formating from Master Sheet
    With Worksheets("Master")
        Range("A" & c.Row & ":F" & c.Row).Copy
    End With
    .Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With

End Sub
```

Here is a link to the spreadsheet: [1drv.ms/x/s!Amd7vhcV4dnOcJsB3KUiCLn6kPI](http://1drv.ms/x/s!Amd7vhcV4dnOcJsB3KUiCLn6kPI).

Any Suggestions?

Comment: While you have been around for some time I'd still like to point out to you the following pages on this site: ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You might also want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can actually reproduce your problem(s). Afterwards, consider updating your post.

Comment: @Ralph Does this code make it more clear? I hope this is what you were referring to when you asked to update the post?

Comment: I think I have fixed the errors. But can you tell me how to provoke the issue #2? What do you do?

Answer (score 0):

Tested the code after I edited on 50 rows, didn't receive any errors. So hopefully it is fixed, or it is very uncommon. And it seems like you are not able to replicate the errors as well?

**Remember** that you have to move out of the current cell that you have added a value to in Column G, before you can move back into it and edit the value to another from the dropdown list.

First of all, add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` after the `Set rng = ...` in the `Worksheet_Change`. This will stop the screen to shimmer, when you add a value in the dropdown list. Add `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` just above the `End Sub` to reset it to standard.

Above `Set rng = ...` add `Dim LastRow As Long`. We will use this to find the last row. Afterwards go to the line after `strFindF = Sheets(..` and add this line `LastRow = Worksheets(cbxOldVal).Cells(Worksheets(cbxOldVal).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`. It will find the last row of the previous sheet, where we are deleting the value for.
After this, replace your `For Loop` with this: `For i = 1 To LastRow`.

The last piece that I want you to add, is so you can try to debug the code yourself when your receive your issue #3 error. Add this between the last `End If` and the newly added `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. It might now be correct, since I am not able to replicate your error. But you should insert a breaking point (F9) somewhere in the code, when you have figured out how to trigger the error.

```
' Debug issue #3
If Target.Value = "" Then
' do nothing
Else
    LastRow = Worksheets(Target.Value).Cells(Worksheets(Target.Value).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print Target.Row
    Debug.Print LastRow

    If Sheets("Master").Cells(Target.Row, 3) = Sheets(Target.Value).Cells(LastRow, 2) Then
        MsgBox "Error #3"
    End If
End If
```